# What is one human power?

Tags: power, biophysics

some time ago I was asked what the HP equivalent of a human was, looking into this apart from in the creation of steam engines the power definition 1 Horse power was set at the work of two of the best London horses nominally 746 watts give or take a bit so the newly invented steam engines would give a good showing I do remember a new scientist article about this but have not been able to find it the article quoted a piece or research into time and motion the increase in work rate of proper rests were included in the pattern and quoted a man loading Iron pigs on a train and properly calculated the actual work done by this man which was awe inspiring putting most athletes to shame

I have limited access to archives and would like a definitive answer the oft quoted wikipedia etc articles are fact weak and at best trivial a link to the original reference work of the new scientist article would be appreciated thanks dotty

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is it about arbitrarily defining a new unit.

Answer (score 3):

1 horsepower is 746 Watts and was designed to compare the power of steam engines with the work done by horses.

You appear to be looking for some comparable number for humans, but of course it depends on the human, so can only be arbitrary.

A reasonable comparison for mechanical work done by an engine could be that provided by someone riding a bicycle. An reasonably fit person could mange a power output of 200 Watts for considerable perods of time on a bike. Tour de France riders might manage to double that quite comfortably.

On the other hand if you were talking about effort over 10 minutes or so, then you could easily double, or perhaps even treble these numbers.

So it is difficult to answer. I would assume that the 746 W corresponded to horses working all day. Therefore it seems best to compare that with a moderately fit human cycling all day. In which case I'd say a horsepower was about 3-4 humanpower.

Comment: I believe the horse comparison assumed sustained output because they were thinking of drawing a plow, pulling a load or turning a pump crank all by walking steadily. Might be a topic for [hsm.se].

Comment: the original research was into sustained work which is why I was interested the figures I remember are amazing which is why I would like to read the original documents the interesting point is Watt measured the power of a horse and doubled it to give the 746 watts ( HP ) so the customers would not be disappointed in that case either the horse power is wrong or the original comments on the experiments were wrong if a human can sustain 300 plus watts in reality the horse should be more than than the implied 370 watts